# How to select information from a record, and the first record after that where some doesn't appear

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, aggregate

I have a table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ts TIMESTAMP,
    expected_departure TIMESTAMP,
    aimed_departure TIMESTAMP,
    stop TEXT,
    service TEXT,
    vehicle_ref TEXT
)
```

I want to find the last record where the identifier `(stop, service, vehicle_ref)` appears, and the first record where none of the rows with the same `ts` returned the same `(stop, service, vehicle_ref)`.

I've tried doing this a number of different ways but haven't been able to figure it out.

It is possible to restructure the data, or even switch to a time-series database, if it makes doing the query simpler.

**EDIT:**
Here's an example, with dates ommited for simplicity:

```
// First API call
id: 1,
ts: 10:00:00,
aimed_departure: 10:30:00
expected_departure: 10:31:00,
stop: 1,
service: 2,
vehicle_ref: 1000

id: 2,
ts: 10:00:00,
aimed_departure: 10:50:00,
expected_departure: 10:50:00,
stop: 1,
service: 3,
vehicle_ref: 2000

// Second API call
id: 3,
ts: 10:32:00,
aimed_departure: 10:50:00,
expected_departure: 10:50:00,
stop: 1,
service: 3,
vehicle_ref: 2000
```

I want to identify, and select from, `id=1,3` because there's a service (`stop: 1, service: 2, vehicle_ref: 1000`) that showed up in the first API call (ts: 10:00:00), but not in the second, (`ts: 10:32:00`).

There might be many calls where the service showed up, but I am only interested in the last it showed up in, and the first it didn't, as long as the difference between `ts` is less than some interval.

Comment: can you share sample data and output

Comment: So for the first request you want the last record where stop , service and vehicle_ref is not null ?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I've added an example. Apologies that the original question wasn't clear, it's hard for me to explain exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

just use max and min and sub-query a nd union all

```
select id,stop, service, vehicle_ref from
   (
     select stop, service, vehicle_ref,T1.id from mytable T1 inner join    
     (select max(id) as id from mytable ) as T2 
      on T1.id=T2.id
    )TT1

union all

select TT4.id,stop, service, vehicle_ref from mytable TT2
inner join 
(

select min(id) as id from
 (
select stop, service, vehicle_ref,min(id) as id from mytable 
group by stop, service, vehicle_ref

  ) TT3
) TT4 on TT2.id=TT4.id
```

here is the output

```
id  stop    service     vehicle_ref
3     1          3        2000
1     1          2        1000
```

Comment: I'm not sure this does exactly what I want. I'm interested on selecting based on `ts`, rather than `id`. Could you have a look at my edit?

Comment: @ZacPullar-Strecker this query so far returned your expected output have you tried it?

Comment: It's pretty close, the issue I have is that it'll always return the most recent row because there's nothing that comes after it. Is it possible to not return that one?

If you have time, it'd also be great if you could break down how the query works. It's very opaque to me.

Comment: @ZacPullar-Strecker i think if you  share  more sample data and what will be their output then  query will be100% accurate as you said pretty close.btw im explain my query

Comment: 1st block before union returned the last record and after union returned the minimum record where none of them are same (stop, service, vehicle_ref)

Comment: Here's some more test data that hopefully illustrates the problem better: https://gist.github.com/zacps/7bc9ad6f718e8d7efe3be2242afca742